# How does one make something real time?

Tags: c++

This might be a really stupid question, but I can't find any info on this, and I can't find out what to search for.

How do you make something real time? For example, say we have a game, how does it run continuously without us calling a tick() method at different parts of the program?

Comment: I have a feeling you'd prefer an answer from http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing the program to run at a time in particular the best way I know of is to develop it to run at a particular loop rate using timed delays.

IE:

```
while(forever) {
    do something
    test how long it took
    take up the remainder amount of time for the loop to run at a rate (ie 100Hz)
}
```

If you are desperate for real time applications you can develop and use QNX:

http://www.qnx.com/

But this certainly wouldn't be a good environment for programming games.